# In English, are trains female?

Tags: pronouns, poetry, grammatical-gender

In the poem **[Night Mail](https://www.oatridge.co.uk/poems/w/wh-auden-night-mail.php)** by W. H. Auden, the eponymous train is always referred to as being female:

> This is the night mail crossing the Border,
> Bringing the cheque and the postal order,
>
> Letters for the rich, letters for the poor,
> The shop at the corner, the girl next door.
>
> Pulling up Beattock, a steady climb:
> The gradient's **against her**, **but she's on time**.
>
> Past cotton-grass and moorland boulder
> Shovelling white steam over **her shoulder**,
>
> Snorting noisily **as she passe**s
> Silent miles of wind-bent grasses.
>
> Birds turn their heads **as she approaches**,
> Stare from bushes at **her blank-faced coaches**.
> […]

Is this common in English usage? Obviously, ships are always referred to as being female, but it it also true of trains?

Comment: Thomas the tank engine is male but his carriages are female so the train they form is...mixed gender?

Comment: Probably the locomotive rather than the whole train. There's a tradition of men referring to powered vehicles, as well as ships, as 'she'. (Rev. W. Awdry notwithstanding.)

Comment: Personification more generally is a common poetic device where inanimate objects are treated as if they were sentient/human.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the gender of an aircraft?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46807/what-is-the-gender-of-an-aircraft) See also [Referring to objects as "she"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3178/referring-to-objects-as-she) and [Pronoun question: referring to inanimate objects as 'he' or 'she'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287721/pronoun-question-referring-to-inanimate-objects-as-he-or-she), among others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks for the link, that helps with some background, but I am specifically interested in the common use for trains.

Comment: Trains are modes of transport (and *containers*, for passengers and freight), so to the (***very*** limited, today) extent that they might be "gendered", they'd normally be female (as ships, planes, etc.). But as has been pointed out, at least Thomas and Gordon are male trains, and of course, there are always homophonous ***mail** trains*. You as a poet can make your own choice. If you're not a poet (or a devoted steam train hobbyist engine driver), you should just forget about gendering trains at all.

Comment: Mark Williams once asked the then driver of the preserved steam locomotive 'Duke of Gloucester' whether the engine was a 'she'. The reply was "Of course." And doubtless likewise (in railfan jargon) for preserved locomotives 'Oliver Cromwell', 'Blue Peter', 'Flying Scotsman', 'Scots Guardsman', 'Sir Nigel Gresley', 'Lord Nelson', 'King George V' ... not to mention 'City of Truro', 'Clun Castle' and 'Union of South Africa'.  The locomotives themselves seem more troubled by water quality than gender identity issues.

Comment: Stagecoaches and chariots seem to be traditionally female as well: "[She'll be coming round the mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She%27ll_Be_Coming_%27Round_the_Mountain) when she comes."

Comment: The question is not a duplicate, because nothing in the other question, or the answers to it, is about trains, or as matter of logic entails anything about trains. The answer to this question is, in fact, analogous to the one about planes (one can find the instances of trains referred to in the feminine gender, but that is nowadays relatively unusual), but nobody can conclude that from reading the answers to the question about aircraft. The fact that a language exhibits one quirk does not guarantee that it will exhibit a similar one, so it is reasonable to ask separate questions about them.

Comment: @jsw29 Look at HotLicks' answer and the comments appended, and Athanasius's answer, at [Pronoun question: referring to inanimate objects as 'he' or 'she'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287721/pronoun-question-referring-to-inanimate-objects-as-he-or-she_?).

Comment: I'm thinking male, because they use the same tired, old lines to pick people up.

Comment: User Ricky once affirmed: [*All ships, airplanes, cars*, ***and locomotives are female.***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/288845/44619)

Comment: @Mari-Lou 'Thomas' and some friends must be seen as an exception, and I'd argue the same for Rodney Matthews' 'Heavy Metal Hero' [[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cuoMsPJ2M2Q)]. But some people see these as being in a distinct and deeper class of make-believe, not just ascribing sentience and gender to inanimate objects.

Comment: By 'Is this common in English usage?' do you mean in the UK?

Comment: Also, note that Auden uses the common metonymy, conflating locomotive and train. 'This is the night mail ' ... 'Shovelling white steam over her shoulder' ... 'Snorting noisily as she passes'.

Comment: No it's not common at all. Outside of poetry or poetic speaking, in real life no one uses gendered pronouns for trains (or boats for that matter).

Comment: Don't forget that some of these might be TRANS!

Answer (score 4):

> In English, are trains female?

No, but trains, along with many, usually large, machines are personified as female.

A: "Nice car!"
B: "Thanks, **She**'s a 1949 SS Jaguar. I've owned **her** for 20 years."

"The ship floundered on the rocks and **her** keel was broken."

"The pressure gauge on the boiler had entered the red zone:  "Get out" shouted the foreman "**She**'s going to explode!"

(All quotes 2022, Greybeard)

Personification has a long history but with the coming of the "machine age" in the early 19th century, the idea took on new life with machines that required a lot of attention and maintenance.

This personification assumed that the owner (or person in charge) of the machine was male (not unreasonable, as they invariably were) and he regarded the machine with love and saw in the machine many of the attributes of a woman - in need of much care and attention, fickle, an object of desire, loyal, hard-working, etc.

Comment: All answered before.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I’ll join in on two conditions:

1. **We confine ourself to *trains*** — not other forms of transport.
2. **We document our quotations** — not rely on invention or hearsay.

And I’ll state what I see as **the problem with trains**. As a form of transport one’s attachment for them is different from that of a ship (historically) in which you trusted your life or made your living. Likewise, a car (@Greybeard) which you might own, use frequently, keep in good order and regard as a sort of extension of yourself. A train is a functional mode of transport which, even for long-distance travel, most people have brief contact with and regard in a utilitarian manner. There is hardly anything romantic about the London Underground or the New York Subway, such that one would consider personifying the grubby assembly of carriages.

*So there is not a lot of adult poetry or literature about trains.*

As a Brit addressing a predominantly North American list membership (some of whom may never have been on a ‘real’ train) all I could think of was that beautiful [Rootabaga Story — *The two skyscrapers who decided to have a child*, by Carl Sandberg](https://www.pbs.org/wnet/americanmasters/carl-sandburg-rootabaga-stories-the-two-skyscrapers-who-decided-to-have-a-child/2206/). A story for children… and adults. The child of this union was a *train*, the *Golden Spike Limited*, so it is interesting to see how Sandberg personified this.

In discussing the future child he personifies it as *female*:

> “It must be a free child,” they said to each other. “It must not be a child standing still all its life on a street corner. Yes, if we have a child **she** must be free to run across the prairie, to the mountains, to the sea. Yes, it must be a free child.”

But thereafter, as a train, he only uses the neuter, *it*:

> So time passed on. Their child came. **It** was a railroad train, the
> Golden Spike Limited…
>
> …so when people spoke of the Golden Spike Limited, they spoke of **it** as
> a strong, lovely child.

*So if the Golden Spike Limited was female it was perhaps because she was a child, not because she was a train.*

**One swallow…**

I shall try to find some more examples as I have been criticized for generalizing (I didn’t) from one.

**T.S.Eliot**, an expatriate American with whom some of you  may be familiar, wrote about a British railway train in his poem [*“Skimbleshanks the Railway Cat”*](https://monologues.co.uk/Childrens_Favourites/Skimbleshanks.htm). In fact this train also went under the name of the “Night Mail” but the focus was on the cat and the passengers travelling the 400 miles from London to Glasgow’s Gallowgate (alas, no longer a railway station). If you read the poem you will see that *not once* is the train personified. It appears as variously “the Night Mail”, “the Northern Mail”, “the Sleeping Car Express” and “the Railway Train”.

*Perhaps the problem was that it was probably ”The Flying Scotsman”.*

And then there was **Noël Coward**. His play, [*Blythe Spirit*](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.210077/2015.210077.Hay-Fever_djvu.txt) (no it isn’t on Netflix), illustrates the romantic attitude of users to the train in its hay-day:

> Myra: Well, Judith, I do think you might have told
> me someone was motoring down. A nice car would have
> been so much more comfortable than **that beastly train**.

*I suppose there is some personification, or at least anthropomorphism, there. But it would be beastly to say he meant it as a ‘she’.*

**But…**

If one considers traditional American folksongs (hundreds of which are listed on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_train_songs), although finding the lyrics is another matter entirely) there are a few counter-examples.

There’s my childhood favourite, [*The Runaway Train*](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=runaway+train+vernon+dalhart+lyrics&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8):

> The runaway train came down the track and **she** blew,

and the [*Wabash Cannonball*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wabash_Cannonball):

> Now listen to the jingle, and the rumble, and the roar,
> As **she** dashes thro’ the woodland, and speeds along the shore,

But, for the most part, the relationship to the railroad of the protagonists of these traditional songs was unromantic. They either worked as convicts in its shadow ([Midnight Special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Special_(song))), killed themselves competing against automation in building it ([John Henry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Henry_(folklore))), or came to an untimely end riding it ([Casey Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ballad_of_Casey_Jones)).

Comment: I hate it when people downvote this sort of answer. However,  you are wrong when you say: most of whom will never have been on a train. A bit much, don't you think?

Comment: There have been a wealth of programs on UK television that most train buffs will have watched. Michael Portillo / Chris Tarrant / Bill Nighy (voiceover) / Rob Bell / Ruth Goodman / ... the list goes on and on. I can't ever remember one footplate worker or fireman referring to their locomotive as other than 'she'. // Mentioning a single anecdote does not usually go a long way towards proving established usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — “Train buffs” says it all. And, yes there are limitations in citing a single **source**  —  NOT **anecdote**. But that seems to be one more than anyone else. I’ll flesh it out with TS Elliot as I don’t have a television.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you. I’ll change it to some. And make a distinction between the Chicago El (or even the South Chicago Railway, if it still exists) and the Flying Scotsman.

Comment: Emily Dickinson: 'The Railway Train
<< I like to see it lap the miles,
And lick the valleys up,
And stop to feed itself at tanks;
And then, prodigious, step >> // Will Carleton: Up the Line
<< Through blinding storm and clouds of night,
We swiftly pushed our restless flight;
With thundering hoof and warning neigh,
We urged our steed upon his way
Up the line. >> // Boodoo: << ... The train is picturesquely framed
A million golden curls
Float gently round its bodyshell
And in its wake they swirl>>

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — Very nice. You can add them as an edit if you wish.

Comment: I'd like to think _you_'d want to give more balance.